# How do I run these functions simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on building some custom social sharing icons. I'm using the following requests to get the count of shares, tweets, etc. from each network. I need all of these requests to be complete prior to running the functions under the "Activate All Other Functions" section. By nesting them the way that I have, it forces them to run one at a time. Is there a way that I can process these such that they all run simultaneously and so that the functions at the bottom do not run until they are all complete?

```
function getShares($URL) {

// Get the Twitter Share Count
 jQuery.getJSON('http://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' + $URL + '&callback=?', function (twitdata) {
    jQuery('.twitter .count').text(ReplaceNumberWithCommas(twitdata.count));
    // Get the LinkedIn Count
    jQuery.getJSON('http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=' + $URL + '&callback=?', function (linkdindata) {
        jQuery('.linkedIn .count').text(ReplaceNumberWithCommas(linkdindata.count));
        // Get Facebook Shares
        jQuery.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' + $URL + '&callback=?', function (facebook) {
            jQuery('.fb .count').text(ReplaceNumberWithCommas(facebook.shares));                
            // Get Pinterest Pins
            jQuery.getJSON('http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?url=' + $URL + '&callback=?', function (pins) {
                jQuery('.nc_pinterest .count').text(ReplaceNumberWithCommas(pins.count));               
                // Get Pinterest Pins
                jQuery.getJSON('http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?url=' + $URL + '&callback=?', function (pins) {
                    jQuery('.nc_pinterest .count').text(ReplaceNumberWithCommas(pins.count));               

                    // Activate All Other Functions
                    createFloatBar();
                    setWidths();
                    floatingBar();
                    activateHoverStates();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

}

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ will do what you want

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. You should put that in the form of an answer so I can select it and up vote it for you. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes wrap everything in

```
$.when()
```

that you want to run simultaneously, when they are all complete , then this `$.then()` will execute

```
$.when( 
    // code to run,
    // code to run ,
    //code to run,
 ).then(function(){

    // runs when everything in top block is finished
});
```

you can Google jQuery Deferred Execution , or jQuery promise

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the async.js library.  It has the added benefit of allowing you to put the results into an object that the final function can use.

https://github.com/caolan/async

Example from the documentation:

```
// an example using an object instead of an array
async.parallel({
    one: function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 1);
        }, 200);
    },
    two: function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 2);
        }, 100);
    }
},
function(err, results) {
    // results is now equals to: {one: 1, two: 2}
});
```

To use with your code, you just put your `getJSON` calls in place of the `setTimeout` calls, placing the `callback` function within and passing the results into it.